# Angular 4 routing and multiple shared layout pages in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular4-router

I have a requirement to have multiple layouts one for public access and the other for secure access in a project done with ASP.Net MVC and Angular 4.

In the Index action of Home controller available at /Home/Index, I initiated the Angular app. My index.cshtml file is below.

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('../app/main').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div>             
        <biz-app></biz-app>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app folder structure is shown below:
[app folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr6du.png)

```
app
   layouts
       public.component.html
       public.component.ts
       secure.component.html
       secure.component.ts
   modules
       public
           login
               login.component.html
               login.component.ts
       secure
           dashboard
               dashboard.component.html
               dashboard.component.ts
           event
               event.component.html
               event.component.ts
   app.component.html
   app.component.ts
   app.module.ts
   app.routing.ts
   main.ts
```

My requirement is, when I go to dashboard or event page, I need to have the secure layout, and public layout for publicly accessible pages.
My question is since I am writing the HTML tags and loading the application from the /Home/Index, how is it possible to have separate layout files for public and secure layout pages?

How is it possible to have separate CSS and JS loaded to public and secure layouts when the original HTML file is outside the app folder?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreasderuiter/2016/01/06/creating-a-security-enabled-angularjs-application-with-asp-net-mvc-the-easy-way-tutorial/

Comment: Hi @Amit, the question was about Angular 4 and not AngularJS. Thank you.